# Can Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain Supports Partial Transaction Encryption?

Tags: private-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

My use case is that we need to protect only sensitive data in the transaction in blockchain. But we want to open other data in the same transaction to the public, Can Hyperledger Fabric supports the above mentioned transaction type? If not, can I achieve it using smart contract and user roles in my organization?

Please advise.  Thanks.

Regards,
Wilson

Comment: First off this the wrong forum for hyper ledger fabric.. you can find them on rocket chat.. seconding fabric is a permissions private chain so you wouldn’t expose any parts of it to the public

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a public blockchain with Hyperledger Fabric (HLF). Everyone is identified by a certificate issued by the CA or they don't get to play.

You can have channels with a subset of network participants. Nothing in the protocol provides encryption. It is assumed that transactions are distributed on channels on a need-to-know basis. Nothing prevents or forbids client-side encryption as an off-chain concern.

A transaction cannot be distributed on more than one channel.

Hope it helps.